# How to get value from all the dropdown field used in a widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I have used the following [widget](https://github.com/enamulhaque028/data/blob/master/dropdown_settings.dart) to show some dropdown from [api](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enamulhaque028/data/master/covertly_data.json). If I used static variable, then a I can get only the value which is selected from the last dropdown field. How can I get all value which have been selected from all the fields?

```
  ExpansionTile(
            iconColor: Color(PrimaryColor),
            collapsedIconColor: Color(PrimaryColor),
            key: new Key(_key.toString()),
            initiallyExpanded: false,
            title: new Text(this.dropDownValue),
            //backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.025),
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: widget.values.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(widget.values[index].name, style: textStyle),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          this.dropDownValue = widget.values[index].name;
                          _collapse();
                        });
                        print(widget.values[index].value);
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            ]),
```

[Dropdown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21vMI.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to be able to select multiple items in the dropdown list? Then what should be the title of the ExpansionTitle?

Comment: I am able to select items from dropdown. In the image you can see that there are several dropdown fields. I have to send the the values from these fields. How can I get the all the values?

Comment: by looking into at your code, the implementation is done in a way that you'll get one value at a time. What you need to do, you'll have to do it by yourself, you can post your full code, then we can help you here

Comment: Dropdown Widget Link: https://github.com/enamulhaque028/data/blob/master/dropdown_settings.dart